# How do I repair or cover up this crack/gap in the drywall on the ceiling?

Tags: drywall, repair, paint

I assume this split apart because of expansion or the house settling. I haven't really noticed if it gets shrinks when it's warmer out.

What's a good way to fix this to where it won't open back up in the future?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It looks like a shrinkage crack. You can apply a flexible sealant to fill the gap. However, most importantly, it looks like the space is too dry. Maintaining the space with moderate humidity could help to minimize the chance of reoccurrence.

Comment: Doesn't help this is directly above a window and a floor vent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Standard repair

Re-tape the affected areas with drywall tape and cover with drywall compound.

For a small section like this, you can try to recreate the texture by hand.  Hardware stores sells texture in a spray can, but it may or may not match the particular look and feel of your walls.  The last time I used the can, it was more of an  orange peel texture.  Looks like your surfaces are coarser, with larger chunks.  You can also buy a super soaker sized texture gun, I've used this and you can dial in the chunk size.  It costs a lot more than the spray can though.

Then there is the hassle of paint matching.  Looks like you have three colors converging here.

### Quick repair, no painting

Fill the gap with drywall compound or caulk, but no tape.  It will likely crack again as the walls expand and contract with seasonal temperature changes.  Hopefully, a much smaller crack that is not so noticeable.  Clean up carefully so that the only new material that shows is the gap fill itself.

For the paint flaking up section, carefully peel back and "glue" it back down.  Try not to pull back to far, or it will crack off.  Can use any paint you have around as glue, but wipe up the excess before it dries, unless the paint is an exact match.

Answer (score 0):

### Aesthetic Repair with Gesso

Assuming there is no underlying paneling issue or structural issue, the cracking and brittling can be aesthetically mitigated by applying several coats of a heavy acrylic primer such as "acrylic gesso".

Acrylic gesso forms a soft flexible and paintable surface over the existing drywall substrate.

Reinsert any loose or brittle parts to keep the original texture. Remove grime, dust and other dirt. Apply several coats of acrylic gesso and roll out to fill cracks deeply but maintain the bumpy look. Deeper cracks can be pre-filled with acrylic caulking, a.k.a "painters caulking".

Then paint with your favourite acrylic paint.

Acrylic gesso is available from arts stores. Make sure you get the "acrylic" variant, not some sort of traditional/original Italian canvass glue.